# image upload error in frozzennode administrator *Laravel*

Tags: php, laravel

I just moved my development area from windows to linux
(linux mint). Am getting an 'HTTP Error' wen I try uploading
images in administrator image field. Only the original image
is uploaded. I think it has to do with the sizes.

Comment: Could you paste some code? Did you check it's not a "pretty links" problem? I mean, the one which makes website/images to website/index.php/images

Comment: does data-www have rights to write to the upload directory ?

Comment: I av given the folder 777 permission. And it works well on windows. This is a similar problem https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator/issues/554 but d solution didnt work 4 me.

Comment: This is the link to my issue https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator/issues/670

Comment: I too have the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GD library wasn't installed. I ran `sudo apt-get install php5-gd` to install it.
Then restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart`